# use of comma before a clause starting with for

Tags: punctuation

Do I use a comma in the following sentence:

Driving is only a means to an end, for most people.

Comment: It's not necessary, though you might prefer to signal a pause-for-thought between the main statement and the caveat. If so, I'd recommend an ellipsis, because it might be expected that the sentence is going to continue: 'Driving is only a means to an end, for most people are not petrol-heads'.

Comment: And I'd rephrase it: For most people, driving is only a means to an end.